# importing pages from different oracle apex work space

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have two workspace in oracle apex. Each has application with aplication id 115 and 116. Each application has different schema. I want to copy a page from one workspace to another workspace . I had done this before by changing the workspace id in the line

```
wwv_flow_api.set_security_group_id(p_security_group_id=>1849003232797416);
```

of my exported page. But now when I opened the exported page in wordpad to replace the workspace id, the  line     **wwv_flow_api.set_security_group_id(p_security_group_id=>1849003232797416);** is not present in the exported page. what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Open your export file and find the following lines:

```
-- SET APPLICATION ID

wwv_flow.g_flow_id := 520;

wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset := 0;
```

You will need to change the line `wwv_flow.g_flow_id` to the application number where you are installing. You will also need to change the line `wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset` to a different number but it doesn't seem to matter which, just keep trying different ones until it installs successfully.

Comment: there is no parameter like  wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset in my exported page

Answer (score 0):

if you use sqlplus to import
first do this:

```
    declare
    l_workspace_id number;

    begin
    apex_application_install.set_workspace('Workspace_name');
    apex_application_install.generate_offset;
    l_workspace_id := apex_util.find_security_group_id (p_workspace => 'Workspace_name');
    apex_util.set_security_group_id (p_security_group_id => l_workspace_id);
    APEX_UTIL.PAUSE(2);

    end;
    /
```